# Performance when using NFS storage for Elasticsearch

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a server with 32 cores, 62 GB of RAM but we have NFS storage and I think it's starting to bottleneck our daily work. In our Kibana errors like `queue_size` are appearing more frequently. We just got a new (same) server to use it as a replica and share the load, will this help? What other recomendations you have? We have multiple dashboards with like 20 different variables each, will they be evenly distributed between the primary node and the replica? Unfortunately, local storage is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Are you actively indexing data on these nodes? If yes you can increase refresh_interval

```
PUT /myindex/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "30s"
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html to make system less demanding for IO. You can completely disable refresh functionality and trigger it manually.

```
PUT /myindex/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "-1"
    }
}

POST /myindex/_refresh
```

Take a look on [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) it significantly decrease load on indexing stage.

Adding new servers to cluster helps too. Elasticsearch designed to scale horizontally. From my experience you can run 6-8 virtual nodes on server you have described. Put more shards to evenly distribute load.

Do you see what is your bottleneck (Lan, IO, CPU)?